# Not that kind of Map exception with Jenkins and Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, scripting

I have a string in groovy that I want to convert into a map. When I run the code on my local computer through a groovy script for testing, I have no issues and a lazy map is returned. I can then convert that to a regular map and life goes on. When I try the same code through my Jenkins DSL pipeline, I run into the exception

```
groovy.json.internal.Exceptions$JsonInternalException: Not that kind of map
```

Here is the code chunk in question:

```
  import groovy.json.*

  String string1 = "{value1={blue green=true, red pink=true, gold silver=true}, value2={red gold=false}, value3={silver brown=false}}"

  def stringToMapConverter(String stringToBeConverted){
      formattedString = stringToBeConverted.replace("=", ":")
      def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().setType(JsonParserType.LAX)
      def mapOfString = jsonSlurper.parseText(formattedString)
      return mapOfString
  }

  def returnedValue = stringToMapConverter(string1)

  println(returnedValue)
```

returned value:

```
[value2:[red gold:false], value1:[red pink:true, gold silver:true, blue green:true], value3:[silver brown:false]]
```

I know that Jenkins and Groovy differ in various ways, but from searches online others suggest that I should be able to use the LAX JsonSlurper library within my groovy pipeline. I am trying to avoid hand rolling my own string to map converter and would prefer to use a library if it's out there. What could be the difference here that would cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
import groovy.json.*

//@NonCPS
def parseJson(jsonString) {
    // Would like to use readJSON step, but it requires a context, even for parsing just text.
    def lazyMap = new JsonSlurper().setType(JsonParserType.LAX).parseText(jsonString.replace("=", ":").normalize())

    // JsonSlurper returns a non-serializable LazyMap, so copy it into a regular map before returning
    def m = [:]
    m.putAll(lazyMap)
    return m
}

String string1 = "{value1={blue green=true, red pink=true, gold silver=true}, value2={red gold=false}, value3={silver brown=false}}"
def returnedValue = parseJson(string1)
println(returnedValue)
println(JsonOutput.toJson(returnedValue))
```

You can find information about `normalize` [here](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/01/groovy-goodness-normalize-and.html).

Comment: hmmm...doesn't seem to be working. Still get same error. I should note the function lives in a Shared library and the originating string is an environment variable although it still is of class java.lang.String